# How to match a variable list of items separated by commas

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I want to turn something like this

```
CS 240, CS 246, ECE 222, ... (more or less); Software Engineering students only
```

into

```
('CS 240', 'CS 246', 'ECE 222', 'ECE 220')
```

in Python, code that matches a single course looks like

```
>>> re.search('([A-Z]{2,5} \d{3})', 'SE 112').groups()
('SE 112',)
```

I prefer a regular expression only method because I have a bunch of other alternate reg exps using '|' to combine them. However, a method with split is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a="CS 240, CS 246, ECE 222"
>>> b=tuple(a.strip() for a in a.split(','))
>>> b
('CS 240', 'CS 246', 'ECE 222')
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the `csv` standard library module ( http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html ) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This method uses regular expressions and matches your input:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\w+\s\d+", "CS 240, CS 246, ECE 222")
['CS 240', 'CS 246', 'ECE 222']
```

It does not look for the comma. Instead it looks for anything *but* the comma: it first matches multiple word characters, then a space character, then multiple digits. [Findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) looks for all occurrences of this pattern.